# How can I visualize measurement accuracy for a continuous variable vs. truth data?

Tags: statistics, visualization

I have measurements for a continuous variable from 3 different tools (let's say remote temperature sensors measuring the same outdoor metal object). I also know the true value in each case. Each tool also gives me a confidence score between 0 and 1 for how accurate it thinks the measurement was. This gives me a table with 7 columns (thermometer #1 reading, thermometer #1 confidence score, thermometer #2 reading, thermometer #2 confidence score, thermometer #3 reading, thermometer #3 confidence score, true temperature) and 100,000 rows.

**My question is - what are the best plots for evaluating the accuracy of 1 or more continuous sensors relative to truth data?**

So far, I've plotted the fraction of readings each tool got exactly right (here the tools are called E, G, and H, and the true temperature varies from -31 to 31 degrees on the x-axis):

[image: plot so far]

I care more about accuracy when the true temperature is > +10, which is also where the tools perform worse, so this plot helps me compare tools in that range, but also across the wider distribution. The downside is that this plot doesn't take confidence scores into account, and also doesn't show whether the tools, when they get it wrong, tend to underestimate or overestimate the true temperature.

I was thinking of plotting ROC curves, but hesitate because there's no binary "true positive" or "false positive".

I am hoping that this is a relatively common type of analysis, and would appreciate suggestions on plot types and metrics that could show which tool is best for getting accurate readings, particularly in the upper ranges.

Comment: This is an interesting problem, but it's off topic here since it's not a specific programming problem; try stats.stackexchange.com instead, you'll find a better audience there. What you really need here is a probability distribution over the observed value for each sensor given the actual temperature, then you can use the laws of probability to turn that around and get a distribution over the actual temperature given the observed values. The difficulty here is that you don't quite have that -- the "confidence scores" are kind of like probabilities of something, but not really what you need.

Comment: You might be able to make progress by making assumptions about the confidence scores to derive probability distributions. Problems like this are near and dear to me; I worked on variations on this them in Chapter 6 of my dissertation (see https://riso.sourceforge.net/ and then partway down the page for the dissertation).

Comment: Thanks. Section 6.5 is particularly relevant. I'm not working on combining the measurements, but this helps me understand a paper that just came out that is.